# using the GET-something instead of instanciation

Tags: android

`NotificationManager notificationManager =                              (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

`LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();`

And there are couple of others.

Why do you use the getXYZ for these and we do not instanciate a new one ?

In which cases such approaches is used ?

Answer (score 1):

This is called [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> Why do you use the getXYZ for these and we do not instanciate a new
>   one?

Because we don't want to have hundreds of `NotificationManagers`, `LayoutInflaters` and others. There is one notification system, so it's convienent to get always one manager and ask him. Imagine working on a project with many almost identical managers who must somehow synchronize information given to all of them. It's easier to have one, who everybody can call :)

> In which cases such approaches is used ?

In a case when you are sure, you don't want to have more than 1 instance of a class. For example `MusicManager` or `RecordsManager` in your game, some `DatabaseConnection` in your app etc.